# Optimizing Live Wallpaper app for efficient battery use (Reduce the battery usage)

Tags: android

I am developing live wallpaper application.

for the one hour and 15 minutes my phone has
been on, live wallpaper has accounted for 26 percent of battery use,
which seems high for changing the wallpaper once per minute?

what i have to do for this problem?

How can i reduce the battery usage. and the application use low battery for the application ?

Comment: This depends on what your live wallpaper is doing.  Maybe run your code through DDMS's method profiler to see what's going on so you have a better idea of what might or might not be sucking down the battery.  Track allocations and such for a while.  Aside from that, I'm not sure there's any proper answer to this without having to go through all of your code, test it, and so on and so forth, which sounds sort of unpleasant.

Comment: on which platform did you compile the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more information about what your wallpaper is doing would be helpful, but here are some things to consider:

Stop/start any drawing loops in onVisibilityChanged. If you are listening for any sensor input stop that here as well. 
Only draw a frame if something has changed. No need for 30fps if you're only updating once a minute.

That's all I can think of at a general level. If you tell me exactly what you're doing I might be able to give you more.

Comment: In My application images which are resides in assets folder i fetch that image and display it on screen according to time interval are like 1 minute, 1 day, 1 month.

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?